# Strategy for distributed-computing inside microservices architecture?

Tags: distributed-computing, microservices

I am looking for advice for the following problem:

- I am working with other people on a microservices architecture where the microservices are distributed on different machines. Resources on the machines are very limited.
- Currently, communication runs through a message broker.
- In my use case, one microservice occasionally needs to run some heavy computation. I would like to perform the computation on a machine with low CPU usage and enough available memory space.

My first idea is that every machine installs a microservice which publishes CPU usage and available memory space in the message broker. Each microservice that needs to distribute their workload is looking for the fittest machines and installs "worker"-microservices on the fly. Results are published in the message broker. Since resources are limited, worker-microservices are uninstalled when not needed anymore.

I haven't found a similar use case yet. Do you guys know a better existing solution?

I am quite new to the topic of microservices and distributed computing, so i would appreciate some advice and help.

Comment: Something like Apache Spark?

Comment: Are these jobs time-sensitive?

Comment: Make a single microservice “observer” and install it only on one node. When other microservice will need to do some computations, let them to delegate work to the “observer”. “Observer” on it's turn could examine all the nodes in the cluster about their capabilities, install computational service on the suitable machine, track progress of computation, resend result to the initial service that requested computations, uninstall computational microservice if there is no need in it in some time interval.

Comment: i think u are trying to develop some kind of simple load balancer mechanizm which is not so easy task if u dig deeper in topic and another downside is u reinventing the wheel: simple solution is to hide those heavy microservices behind some kind of load balancer (for example haproxy) which would choose best endpoint according to some indicators like CPU usage. So u will not have to design loadbalancing logic.